# Wordpress gadget disappears after drag & drop

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hey, why my widgets disappear from Available Widgets list after I drag&drop them?

How to avoid this?

Built-in Wordpress widgets have unlimited "instances" so I can use one widget in few widget areas and that's what I want to achieve with mine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the widget class

http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets

it would have unlimited instances.

If it is only showing up once I would guess that you have not built your widget as a class that extends the widget class.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing extra spaces from the end of your theme's functions.php and your widget's php file.